# SQL Server Management Studio / Visual Studio regular expression bug?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, ssms

I quite often use the regular expression search and replace in SQL Server Management Studio 10.5 editor to clean up auto generated sql before use.  The same behaviour described below occurs in Visual Studio 2010 editor as well.

I have the following sql insert statement that I'd like to clean up:

```
INSERT INTO [lttadev].[dbo].[GameInst]
           ([GameInstId]
           ,[GameSetId]
           ,[UserInfoId]
           ,[GameLevelId]
           ,[CreatedOn]
           ,[CreatedBy]
           ,[ModifiedOn]
           ,[ModifiedBy])
     VALUES
           (<GameInstId, uniqueidentifier,>
           ,<GameSetId, uniqueidentifier,>
           ,<UserInfoId, uniqueidentifier,>
           ,<GameLevelId, uniqueidentifier,>
           ,<CreatedOn, datetime,>
           ,<CreatedBy, uniqueidentifier,>
           ,<ModifiedOn, datetime,>
           ,<ModifiedBy, uniqueidentifier,>)
```

To alter the values clause I have the two following regular expressions:

```
,[^,]*,\>
\<
```

Both are replaced by an empty string to delete the unwanted text.  The first one strips out the comma, type, second comma and final angle bracket.  The second one strips out the initial angle bracket.  Both work as expected.

However if I join the regexes up into a single expression to speed the text processing, they select different text:

```
(,[^,]*,\>|\<)
```

The first expression selects the expected text.  However the second expression gets the first angle bracket as well as the preceding comma.  Is this a defect in the regular expression engine or am I not understanding something here?

Comment: What regular expression dialect do you think you are using here? VS and SSMS have their own special dialect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx

Comment: I was under the impression that both use the same dialect.  The working expressions work in both Visual Studio and SSMS.  The non working expression fails in both Visual Studio and SSMS.

Comment: I meant a different dialect than the .NET one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  I'm using the dialects provided by the Visual Studio 2010 editor and the SSMS editor in their search and replace dialogs.

Comment: That's what I was asking. Some people think the dialect is the same as the .NET one.

Comment: Re: "However the second expression gets the first angle bracket as well as the preceding comma": How can you tell that it's the *second* expression that does this?

Comment: By the way, have you tried `(,[^,]*,\>)|\<` -- putting the first alternant in parentheses, instead of the whole pattern? (In normal regexes this wouldn't be necessary, since alternation has very low priority, but maybe Find-and-Replace regexes are different in this respect?) And for safety's sake, you might want to use `[^,\n]*` instead of `[^,]*`, so that you don't get spurious line-spanning matches.

Comment: I'm not SURE it's the second expression matching.  I'm guessing based on the expectation that something matching the first expression would have to have a > in it.

Comment: @ruakh Thanks for the advice.  `(,[^,]*,\>)|\<` fixed it.  If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.  Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the first alternative in parentheses:

```
(,[^,]*,\>)|\<
```

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) doesn't indicate what precedence `|` has, and it gives only this example:

```
(sponge|mud) bath
```

but elsewhere on that page are various examples where `|` is used with parentheses that would have been unnecessary (though harmless) in another regex engine:

```
(("[^"]*")|('[^']*'))
(- [a-z][1-3])|(- [0-9][a-z])
(([0-9]+.[0-9]*)|([0-9]*.[0-9]+)|([0-9]+))
```

so I'm guessing that `|` might have a fairly high precedence — lower than the trivial within-string concatenation of `sponge` or `mud`, but higher than more complex concatenations like in `"[^"]*"`. (Of course, that last expression was written by someone who didn't notice that `.` has a special meaning, so it may warrant a grain of salt.)

Since I don't have Visual Studio, I can't test this out further.